# PYTHON: How to get seaborn attributes to reset to default?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I cannot for the life of me get seaborn to go back to default settings.
I will place the code that I believe caused this issue, **but I would recommend against running it** unless you know how to fix it.
The culprit I believe is in the last chunk
sns.set(font_scale = 4)
before this question gets deleted because it's already been asked, I have tried the other posted solutions  with no success. Just to name a quick few, resetting using sns.set(), sns.set_style(), sns.restore_defaults(). I have also tried resetting matplot settings to defaults as well. This attribute persists across all my files, so I cant even open a new file, delete the line of code that caused it, or run any past programs, or it will apply to those graphs too.
My seaborn version is 0.10.1, I have tried to update it, but I cant get it to go through. I am using anaconda's spyder IDE
The documentation says for versions after 0.8 that the styles/themes must be invoked to be reset, but if I try to use their solution sns.set_theme() I get an error saying that this module has no attribute.
I'm sure this persistence is considered a feature, but I desperately need it to go away!

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    #data prep
    data_path = './assets/'
    out_path = './output'
    #scraping javascript map data via xml
    endpoint = "https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/COVIDData/getAjaxData"
    data = requests.get(endpoint, params={"id": "US_MAP_DATA"}).json()
    #convert to df and export raw data as csv
    df = pd.DataFrame(data["US_MAP_DATA"])
    path = os.path.join(out_path,'Raw_CDC_Data.csv')
    df.to_csv(path)
    
    #Remove last data point (Total USA)
    df.drop(df.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
    #Create DF of just 50 states
    state_abbr =["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA", 
          "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", 
          "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", 
          "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", 
          "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"]
    
    
    states = df[df['abbr'].isin(state_abbr)]
    #Adding NYC to state of NY
        # FILL THIS IN LATER
    #Graphing
    plt.style.use('default')
    sns.set()
    #add new col survival rate and save
    states['survival_rate']=states['tot_cases']-states['tot_death']
    states.drop(df.columns[[0]],axis=1)
    states.reset_index(drop=True)
    path = os.path.join(out_path,'CDC_Data_By_State.csv')
    states.to_csv(path)
    #Stacked BarPlot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    colors = ['#e5c5b5','#a8dda8']
    r=range(0,len(states.index))
    plt.bar(r,states['survival_rate'],color=colors[0])
    
    #ax = stacked['survival_rate','tot_death'].plot.bar(stacked=True, color=colors, ax=ax)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,35))
    sns.set(font_scale=4)
    ax = sns.barplot(x='tot_cases',y='abbr',data=states)
    ax.set(title='USA Covid-19 Cases by State', ylabel='State', xlabel='Confirmed Cases')
    path = os.path.join(out_path,'Total_Deaths_Bar.png')
    plt.savefig(path)
```

Comment: First, go to the Anaconda prompt and run `conda update --all`. There's no reason seaborn shouldn't be able to update. _seaborn to go back to default settings_ unless you have changed a file, there are no setting retained permanently. `import seaborn as sns` loads seaborn with its default settings.

Comment: In the documentation, it mentions this:
(Note that in versions of seaborn prior to 0.8, set_theme() was called on import. On later versions, it must be explicitly invoked).
is this not what sets seaborn to default settings?

Comment: Only if you want something other than the default settings.

Comment: that seems to have fixed it! thanks